# SharePoint Online Library - Modify Choice column value without Edit in Grid View

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a SharePoint Online Document Library where I need the users to be able to select a Choice field value (Approved, Rejected, etc.) without having to Edit in Grid View.

I know it's possible with JSON formatting, but I can't remember the formula I've used before.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharePoint JSON column formatting for your requirements. You will have to add below line for your main (outer most) `elmType` in JSON:

```
"inlineEditField": "@currentField",
```

**Examples**:

You can use simple JSON like below (without choice pills):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "inlineEditField": "@currentField",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Or use JSON like below with choice pills and inline edit:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "inlineEditField": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "flex-wrap": "wrap",
    "display": "flex"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "display": "flex",
        "border-radius": "16px",
        "height": "24px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "margin": "4px 4px 4px 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "@currentField",
                "Approved"
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-MintGreenFont",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "@currentField",
                    "Rejected"
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgDustRose sp-css-borderColor-DustRoseFont sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-DustRoseFont",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "@currentField",
                        ""
                      ]
                    },
                    "",
                    "sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

---

You can also use `[$FieldName]` instead of `@currentField` in JSON. Where `FieldName` is the internal name of your SharePoint list choice column.

You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)